# Why is this chess unicode character (♔ / U+2654) not being printed by wprintf in C?

Tags: c

main.c

```c
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");
    wchar_t piece = 0x2654;
    wprintf(L"HELLO (%lc)", piece);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
PS gcc -o main.exe -I include src/*.c ; ./main.exe
HELLO ()
```

Expected Output:

```
PS gcc -o main.exe -I include src/*.c ; ./main.exe
HELLO (♔)
```

I am using Powershell in Windows Terminal within VS Code.

What I have tried:

- Changing the terminal font to ones that explicitly support the pieces. The behaviour does not change. It is possible to copy and paste the chess characters into the terminal, however.
- Checking the size of `wchar_t`

```c
printf("%d", sizeof(wchar_t));
// Output: 2 (unsigned short)
```

- Alternate printing methods

```c
printf("♔"); /* and */ printf("\u2654");
// Output: ÔÖö
```

```c
wprintf(L"\u2654");
// Output: [No Output]
```

```c
wprintf(L"♔");
// Output: [No Output]
```

```c
printf("\xE2\x99\x94");
// Output: ÔÖö
```

```c
wchar_t piece[] = L"♔";
wprintf(L"HELLO (%ls)", piece);
// Output: HELLO ()
```

Comment: Does the terminal support Unicode characters? Will it display other characters?

Comment: @WeatherVane yes. Windows PS supports Unicode UTF8 by default.

Comment: Can you copy the `♔` character a paste it into terminal manually?

Comment: @DaBler yes I can.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/2664

Comment: @HansPassant what is the implication of that issue for me?

Comment: If the font you have selected in the terminal does not have a glyph for the symbol then font fallback isn't going to solve the problem.  Run the charmap.exe applet to have a look.

Comment: @HansPassant I have tried multiple fonts with support for the chess pieces in the PS terminal. Unfortunately, the behaviour does not change.

Comment: Slight variation of earlier suspicions: can you run `echo ♔`? On my PC, it renders the input as `?` and the output as `□` (.notdef), so being able to input it may not mean it can be output. Forward-thinking: using symbols that cannot be commonly rendered may make portability a concern for your application (as opposed to, say, `K Q R N B P`).

Comment: @Rogue The same character is printed. No unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Try using `wprintf` with your second example to see if it prints the pieces (don't forget to prefix the strings with `L`). My next suspicion surrounds the `wchar_t` assignment: I believe it is a 16-bit type on windows, but for sanity, check `sizeof(wchar_t)`, since it is supposed to support UTF-16 code points. If your string is hitting a null terminator (written in from excess bytes on `piece`), then it would abruptly end.

Comment: @Rogue I have updated my post with your suggestions.

Comment: Interesting results, I'm out of time for now but look forward to either an answer or solving it myself tomorrow.

Comment: If Windows terminal supports UTF-8 by default, you should be outputting UTF-8 from your print statements, not wide characters. The UTF-8 for a crown is `0xE2 0x99 0x94`.

Comment: And you can use the normal width `printf`

Comment: Try calling `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16_TEXT);`. You will also need `#include <fcntl.h>` to define `_O_U16_TEXT` and `#include <stdio.h>` to define `_setmode()` and `_fileno()`.

Comment: Thank you @IanAbbott! That has worked. Please feel free to post the solution as your own answer. Otherwise I will add the answer myself later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows programs can use the [`_setmode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setmode?view=msvc-170) function to set the [translation mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/translation-mode-constants?view=msvc-170) of an already opened file.

`_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_WTEXT);` or `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);` will set the file descriptor of the `stdout` stream to UTF-16LE translation mode. `_setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);` will set it to UTF-8 translation mode. (The difference between `_O_WTEXT` and `_O_U16TEXT` only applies when opening a file, and determines the handling of BOM (byte order mark) when reading or writing a file.)

Example using `_O_U16TEXT`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT);
    wchar_t piece = 0x2654;

    wprintf(L"HELLO (%lc)", piece);
    return 0;
}
```

Hex dump of UTF-16LE output bytes from the program above:

```
48 00 45 00 4c 00 4c 00 4f 00 20 00 28 00 54 26 29 00
```

Example using `_O_U8TEXT`:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);
    wchar_t piece = 0x2654;

    wprintf(L"HELLO (%lc)", piece);
    return 0;
}
```

Hex dump of UTF-8 output bytes from the program above:

```
48 45 4c 4c 4f 20 28 e2 99 94 29
```

(Note: `e2 99 94` is the UTF-8 sequence for the U+2654 character.)

---

Whether or not the `♔` character will be displayed correctly by the terminal depends on whether the terminal is using a suitable font and/or whether it can use font substitution to render characters not in its current font. None of the standard Windows monospaced fonts such as Cascadia Mono, Consolas, Courier New, or Lucida Console include the character so the classic Windows console will not display the character correctly when using one of those fonts. (The third-party font "DejaVu Sans Mono" *does* include the character, and the character will be displayed properly if the console is set to use that font.) The new Windows Terminal does seem to do font substitution when necessary, so will display the character from some other font even if the normal terminal font it is using does not include the character.

Comment: Another good reason to always install the DejaVu ttf fonts (sans, serif and mono).

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")`, you might want to try:

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF8");
```

or

```
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, ".utf8");
```

and use `printf` to print the output as bytes:

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>

int main(void) {
    /* using raw UTF-8 encoding */
    printf("HELLO \xE2\x99\x94\n");

    /* using source code encoding */
    printf("HELLO ♔\n");

    /* using the C library locale conversion */
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "en_US.UTF8");
    wchar_t piece = 0x2654;
    printf("HELLO %lc\n", piece);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately, the behaviour has not changed with either option.

Comment: The character appears to be encoded as ucs2, not utf-8

Comment: @Blundergat: can you try the above code?

Comment: UTF-8 expects 8 bit characters. To print the crown, you'd need the `uint8_t` sequence `E2 99 94`